# Open a vue component from a method once a button is clicked on a dialog box in Vue.Js

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2

I have two vue components which are the following:

**firstcomponent.vue**

```
<template>
<div class="profile-setup" v-show="profile">
    <div class="md-layout md-gutter">
        <div class="md-layout-item md-size-100">
            <div class="md-title">Setup your profile</div>
        </div>
        <div class="md-layout-item md-size-50">
            <md-field>
                <label>Names</label>
                <md-input v-model="real"></md-input>
                <span class="md-helper-text">Your real names</span>
            </md-field>
        </div>
        <div class="md-layout-item md-size-50">
            <md-field>
                <label>Display Name</label>
                <md-input v-model="display"></md-input>
                <span class="md-helper-text">Your display name</span>
            </md-field>
        </div>
        <div class="md-layout-item md-size-50">
            <md-field>
                <label>Account Name</label>
                <md-input v-model="account"></md-input>
                <span class="md-helper-text">Your account name</span>
            </md-field>
        </div>
        <div class="md-layout-item md-size-50">
            <md-field>
                <label>Phone number</label>
                <span class="md-prefix">+250</span>
                <md-input v-model="number" type="number"></md-input>
                <span class="md-helper-text">Your phone number</span>
            </md-field>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <md-dialog-confirm
                        :md-active.sync="active"
                        md-title="Account created!"
                        md-content="Do you want to create <strong>RWPay</strong> account?"
                        md-confirm-text="Yes"
                        md-cancel-text="No thanks"
                        @md-cancel="onCancel"
                        @md-confirm="onConfirm" />
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <md-dialog-actions>
        <md-button class="md-dense md-raised md-primary" @click="active = true">Save</md-button>
    </md-dialog-actions>
</div>
```

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'firstcomponent',
        data: () => ({
            real: null,
            display: null,
            account: null,
            number: null,
            active: false,
            value: null,
            profile: true
        }),

        methods: {
            onConfirm () {
                console.log('second confirmed');
            },
            onCancel () {
                console.log('second canceled');
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**secondcomponent.vue**

```
<template>
<div class="secondcomponent">
    <md-tabs md-alignment="centered">
        <md-tab id="tab-mobile" md-label="Mobile Money" to="/components/tabs/mobile">
            <div class="md-layout md-gutter">
                <div class="md-layout-item md-size-100">
                    <md-field>
                        <label>Phone number</label>
                        <span class="md-prefix">+250</span>
                        <md-input v-model="number" type="number"></md-input>
                    </md-field>
                </div>
            </div>
        </md-tab>

        <md-tab id="tab-card" md-label="Debit/Credit Card" to="/components/tabs/card">
            <div class="md-layout md-gutter">
                <div class="md-layout-item md-size-100">
                    <md-field>
                        <label>Card type</label>
                        <md-select v-model="cardtype" name="cardtype" id="cardtype" md-dense>
                            <md-option value="visa">Visa</md-option>
                            <md-option value="mastercard">Mastercard</md-option>
                            <md-option value="american-express">American Express</md-option>
                        </md-select>
                    </md-field>
                </div>
                <div class="md-layout-item md-size-100">
                    <md-field>
                        <label>Card number</label>
                        <md-input v-model="card" maxlength="16"></md-input>
                    </md-field>
                </div>
                <div class="md-layout-item md-size-50">
                    <md-field>
                        <label>Expiry date</label>
                        <md-input v-model="month" maxlength="2"></md-input>/
                        <md-input v-model="year" maxlength="2"></md-input>
                    </md-field>
                </div>
                <div class="md-layout-item md-size-50">
                    <md-field>
                        <label>CSC</label>
                        <md-input v-model="exp" maxlength="3"></md-input>
                    </md-field>
                </div>
            </div>
        </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
    <md-dialog-actions>
        <md-button class="md-dense md-raised">Cancel</md-button>
        <md-button class="md-dense md-raised md-primary">Save</md-button>
    </md-dialog-actions>
</div>
```

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'secondcomponent',
        data: () => ({
            number: null,
            cardtype: null,
            card: null,
            month: null,
            year: null
        })
    }
</script>
```

So, i want that when i click on the **Yes** button on dialog box it opens the secondcomponent.vue, When i click **No thanks** it goes to another that i'll specify later.

And i'm using Vue in laravel. Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

What do you exactly mean with "open the secondcomponent.vue"

You mean it should display it in the same context? Or route it to a specific route?

If you just want to show it in the same context you can use [dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html)

Define the names in your component1 data and switch based on your modal methods that are called.

```js
 <script>
        import SecondComponent from 'secondcomponent.vue'
        import ThirdComponent from 'thirdcomponent.vue'
    
        export default {
          name: 'firstcomponent',
          components: {Secondcomponent, Thirdcomponent },
          data: () => ({
            real: null,
            display: null,
            account: null,
            number: null,
            active: false,
            value: null,
            profile: true,
            showAdditionalInfo: false,
            additionalInfo: null
          }),
    
          methods: {
            onConfirm () {
                this.showAdditionalInfo = true
                this.additionalInfo = 'secondcomponent'
            },
            onCancel () {
                this.showAdditionalInfo = true
                this.additionalInfo = 'thirdcomponent'
            }
          }
        }
    
    </script>
```

3. Place the `component` tag where you want your components

---

So that was for the case that it is in the same scope.
If you want to redirect to a specific view it gets tricky without vue-router.

I would suggest that you then just build a wrapper around it and emit an event in your first component on the cancel and confirm methods. Listen on it on the component and then conditionally render them. (You could utilize dynamic components here, too.)

```
<FistComponent @first="handleFirst" @second="handleSecond"/>
<SecondComponent v-if="showSecond" />
<ThirdComponent v-if="showThird" />
```

Comment: Yes I want to show the secondcomponent.vue in the same context.  So, is it possible to define the secondcomponent name in the first one where it will be called?

Comment: Yes I updated the code example.  You need to import both components you want to show the one for the confirm method and the cancel method.

In your template you can then add the `<component :is="" />` component.

And change the name in your confirm and cancel methods

Comment: When I import both the second and third components it sends an error **Module not found** ! and keep in mind that I want to display those components in a same vue component which is the first (so technically the first on has to be hidden when I select Yes or No)

Comment: Oh okay! Then you need to go with the wrapper component. So the second one. 
And emit events from your first component listen to it and then conditionally render

Comment: The think is i'm calling the firstcomponent in a **blade.php** which is the wrapper, and after displaying that firstcomponent.vue in a blade.php ,  I have to do the conditions to display whether to show secondcomponent or thirdcomponent